# Ruby: evaluation order depends on whitespace and seemingly redundant parens, why?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of arithmetic methods in Ruby. `1 .+ 2 .* 3` and `1 .+ (2) .* 3` and `1. + 2. * 3` and `1. + (2). * 3` and `1.+2.*3` all evaluate to 7, which means `:+` is called before `:*`, but `1.+(2).*3` evaluates to 9, which means `:*` is called before `:+`. Redefining both methods confirms that that's what's happening:

```
class Integer
    alias_method :add, :+
    alias_method :mul, :*
    def + other
        print :+
        self.add other
    end
    def * other
        print :*
        self.mul other
    end
end

puts 1 .+ 2 .* 3
puts 1 .+ (2) .* 3
puts 1. + 2. * 3
puts 1. + (2). * 3
puts 1.+2.*3
puts 1.+(2).*3
```

Output:

```
*+7
*+7
*+7
*+7
*+7
+*9
```

Why does it happen? Please point me where to find the relevant documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you ever want to call it that way when `1 + 2 * 3` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give an example that might be easier to understand

```
puts (2) + 3
```

vs

```
puts(2) + 3
```

In the first case, puts is followed by a space. Ruby takes it as omitted parentheses and evaluates the rest as the argument. It's equvalent to `puts((2) + 3)`. 5 is printed. In the 2nd case, puts is immediately followed by a left parenthesis and ruby takes that as the beginning of method arguments. It's equivalent to `(puts(2)) + 3`. It will print a 2 and then fail when trying to evaluate `nil + 3`.

Now lets look at your examples

```
puts 1 .+ 2 .* 3
puts 1 .+ (2) .* 3
puts 1. + 2. * 3
puts 1. + (2). * 3
puts 1.+2.*3
```

In the first 6 cases, no method call is immediately followed by `(`, all the parentheses are redundant. They are evaluated right to left. Note that not `*` before `+`, but right to left.

```
puts 1 .* 2 .+ 3 #=> 5
```

In the last example `puts 1.+(2).*3`, the `(` immediately follows `.+`, so `2` is an argument to `.+`. The result is then multiplied by 3.

Comment: "Note that not * before +, but right to left.": that clarifies a lot, thanks. Indeed, `2 .* 3 .+ 3` evaluates to 12 and not to 9.